# Swift 3: ScrollView in a View Controller with NavBar is cutoff on the top because its behind the custom menu bar. How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

When using ScrollView in a Navigation Bar Controller with a custom menu bar(collection view) right under the navbar(50px height), my scroll view is cutoff on the top because its behind the custom menu bar. How can place ScrollView underneath the custom menu bar?

Custom Menu bar code:

```
lazy var menuBar : MenuBar =
{
    let mb = MenuBar()
    mb.viewController = self
    return mb
}()

private func setupMenuBar()
{
    view.addSubview(menuBar)

    //Add constraints to view menubar under nav bar
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-60-[v0(50)]|", views: menuBar)
}
```

Comment: Can you show storyboard/code ?

Comment: I added the custom menu bar code. The scroll view is a normal scroll view that has constraints: cenerX, centerY, equal Width and equal Height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this at `func viewWillAppear()`  .

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: I tried this but it pushed my scrollview higher. Ill mess around with this method. Thank you for this direction. Hopefully it works. Ill keep you posted.

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know, I added in viewDidLoad(),

`scrollView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

This line worked perfectly after I altered the initial height on my scrollView. Thanks again for the suggestion.